# How to get table A and count of table B with Linq to Sql group by

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a Linq to SQL query that I want to return select columns from all matching rows from one table (TableC in my simplified query below) and a count of matching rows in another table (TableB in below). Certain other tables need to be involved too for the where clause to work (removed in simplified query).

How do I get the columns I need from TableC and a count of TableB?

This is a simplified version of my query:

```
var q = from a in dc.TableA
        from b in dc.TableB
        join c in dc.TableC on b.TableBID equals c.ID
        join d in dc.TableD on a.ID equals d.TableAID
        where 1 == 1 //lots of interesting stuff here
        group c by new { b, c } into g
        select new
        {
            ID = g.Key.c.ID,
            Name = g.Key.c.Name,
            Count = g.Count()
        };
```

Update: I think I found a solution using group joins - answer posted below. I would still like to know if that was the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution after reading about Linq group joins.

```
var q = from a in TableC
        join b in (from c in TableB
                   where (from d in TableA
                          join f in TableD on d.ID equals f.ID
                          where 1 == 1 //for simplicity
                          select d).Any()
                   && 1 == 1 //more simplification
                   select c) on a.TableBID equals b.ID into g
        where 1 == 1 //more simplification
        select new
        {
            a.ID,
            a.Name,
            Count = g.Count()
        };
```